# Property assignments are repeated by tsc run build

Tags: typescript

I'm learning TypeScript and don't understand what the compiler (tsc) is doing here.

I have the following .ts file

```
class Product {
    constructor(public name: string, public unitPrice: number) {
        this.name = name;
        this.unitPrice = unitPrice;
    }
    getDiscountedPrice(discount: number): number {
        return this.unitPrice = discount;
    }
}
```

When I run the command **tsc run build** it outputs product.js as expected but the transpiled code is confusing.

```
var Product = /** @class */ (function () {
    function Product(name, unitPrice) {
        this.name = name;
        this.unitPrice = unitPrice;
        this.name = name;
        this.unitPrice = unitPrice;
    }
    Product.prototype.getDiscountedPrice = function (discount) {
        return this.unitPrice = discount;
    };
    return Product;
}());
```

Why does the transpiler repeat the lines where arguments are assigned to this.name and this.unitPrice?  Is this a bug or is there a reason for assigning the values twice?

Update - based on the initial replies, I'm not explaining the question very well.  To clarify, the entire JS file shown above is not my code, at least it's not written verbatim by my hand.  The only code I wrote is the .ts file shown first.

My question pertains to these lines written by the transpiler which seem redundant to me:

```
this.name = name;
this.unitPrice = unitPrice;
this.name = name;
this.unitPrice = unitPrice;
```

Why are these assignments created twice by tsc?

Comment: They're [parameter properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#parameter-properties).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected because when you declare members in the constructor using `private`/`protected`/`public`. (Don't forget, this is not a JS feature but a TS syntactic sugar) :

```
constructor(public name: string, public unitPrice: number) {}
```

it gets transpiled to :

```
constructor(name, unitPrice) {
    this.name = name;
    this.unitPrice = unitPrice;
}
```

Your code is actually redundant :

```
    this.name = name;
    this.unitPrice = unitPrice;
```

Comment: I know those lines are redundant, and that's the crux of the question.  To clarify, I didn't write them, the transpiler did.  So why is it doing that?

Comment: The lines you wrote within the constructor are redundant since they will be created by the transpiler because you're using paramter properties (private/protected/public) in the constructor. PTAL https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#parameter-properties

Comment: Thanks for clarifying Matthieu, that did indeed fix the problem and remove the duplicate lines from the transpiled .js file.